# cin checking input only numbers in range from 0 to 255

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

```
cin >> red_rgb;
```

How to check the red_rgb, green_rgb, blue_rgb variable when entering it, so that only values in the range from 0 to 255 are allowed, while only integers {0,1,2...254,255} are counted, otherwise, you will need to enter the correct value.

```
int red_rgb = 0;
int green_rgb = 0;
int blue_rgb = 0;    

std::cout << "Enter R: ";
        while (!(cin >> red_rgb) || !(red_rgb >= 0 && red_rgb <= 255))
        {
            cout << "Error";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        std::cout << "Enter G: ";
        while (!(cin >> green_rgb) || !(green_rgb >= 0 && green_rgb <= 255))
        {
            cout << "Error";
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            
        }
        std::cout << "Enter B: ";
        while (!(cin >> blue_rgb) || !(blue_rgb >= 0 && blue_rgb <= 255))
        {
            cout << "Error";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
```

This method tests for a range, but skips semicolons. And if you enter letters instead of numbers, the more letters there are, the more times the cycle will start.

if you enter a float, the cycle for entering the next value is skipped
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfX85.png)

Comment: By default `ignore()` only ignores a single character, but you can pass a higher number as a parameter.

Comment: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`

Comment: Yes, I corrected this problem about `cin.ignore()` but values such as 4.5, 3f, 0,01 works.  
Need to check this variable for integer.

Comment: Are `red_rgb` and the likes of type `int`?

Comment: Yes, int red_rgb;

Comment: There are many dupes here about validating integer input in C++, the gist is that you better input a string and then parse it (using [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), [`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)), checking that *all* the chars are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
int inprgb(const string& hint){
    int a=-1;
    while (true){
      cout << hint;
      cin>>a;
      if (cin.fail() || cin.peek()!=10 ||!(a >= 0 && a <= 255) ) {
          cin.clear();
          cout << "Error\n";
          cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
          continue;
      }
      break;
    }
    return  a;
};
```

and

```
red_rgb = inprgb("Enter R: ");
```